# How similar are the spin states and the matter/antimatter states?

Tags: quantum-spin, antimatter, dirac-equation, spinors

Within the Dirac formalism, we have bispinors that represent both if a particle is spin up or spin down, and if a particle is an electron or a positron.

And these representations are very similar.  (Along the z axis).

$\psi_{electron, up}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$,  $\psi_{electron, down}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\psi_{positron, up}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$\psi_{positron, up}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

How close is the analogy between these two kinds of states?  What properties of spin have a counterpart in the matter/antimatter state?